# With Drupal 7 tokens, how do I get the path from a custom link field?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, token, custom-field-type, display-suite

This must be trivial, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to get the URL/path portion of a link field with tokens. I am using the Display Suite module and want to make the entire teaser of a node link to the URL specified in a link field.

So in the Custom Wrapper GUI for a node display type, I pick "Add Link as Token" and add this token:

```
[node:field-goto-link]
```

This gets me the hyperlink, so I thought I could do:

```
[node:field-goto-link:url]
```

...but that isn't a valid token.
So what are the sub-pieces to a link?

Comment: If you have a field-goto-link field, then with [node:field-goto-link] you link the teaser to that link. I don't really understand your problem. Your teaser link is not working? I tried it as you described with [node:field-goto-link], and it linked my teaser to that link...

Comment: I end up going to this URL:<a%20href%3D"http%3A//MY-URL">MY-LINK_TITLE</a>

...my hope/belief was that I just had the token wrong, namely I needed to select the path portion of the link object.

Comment: Having the same problem, I want to link a teaser content to a custom url, so I created a link field, and tried with display suite to link the content to the field using tokens, but not working... Same problem 9 Month ago here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2092509

Answer (score 1):

By sure those token that not appear in your list is not available, make sure to enable entity token to have access to field link URL.
on my case the token is [node:field-link:url]